# Setting Path of TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2 Early 2016 Rose Gold MacBook

I have done a LOT to get TensorFlow installed (REALLY should have just used pip3 from the start...) and now need to set the path of it so I can import it. Currently, I know it is installed; `pip3 show tensorflow` gets `Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.8.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: numpy, absl-py, gast, termcolor, astor, protobuf, grpcio, wheel, six, tensorboard`

This is great, but importing tensorflow still doesn't work. I figured out that I need to set the path from some googling and found this command: `PYTHONPATH=/your/tensorflow/path:$PYTHONPATH`. However, what am I supposed to do with it? Should I replace 'PYTHONPATH' with something? How do I tell it that that points to `tensorflow`? Should it be like this:
`PYTHONPATH=/Users/rose/tensorflow/path:$tensorflow`

Comment: help('modules package') in the python on your env and see if is there. I suspect that is not in the environment . Your location is not pointing to your env so is in the default python machine, just try without environment the python and you'll see is there ...

Comment: @0709_ Sorry, could you explain that a little more clearly (very little experience with using Terminal to download Python stuff)? I know tensorflow is on my computer and Virtualenv is downloaded, what does what you said mean?

Comment: so you go inside of your env aka tensorflow, open python and with help('modules package')  check the packages if are inside, based on what you provided the package is on the original shipped OS python ...

Comment: So cd to tensorflow?

Comment: yes and activate, thank check the tensorflow if is there ...

Comment: So what package should I look for on the help screen?

Comment: So I should do that source .bin/activate thing? I think I'm using pip3 because virtualenv wasn't working

Comment: yes that thing (.bin/activate), why not use the anaconda instead of virtenv ? is easier and all this problem will be solved easy ...

Comment: Oh, virtualenv was recommended on the TensorFlow site

Comment: source .bin/activate and just .bin/activate both got `-bash: .bin/activate: No such file or directory` (`Macbook:tensorflow rose$ ` shows, so I am in the tensorflow directory)

Comment: Maybe I should use Anaconda instead

Comment: It has a GUI, right? I hate Terminals

Comment: @0709_ Thank you so much! I'm gonna try using Anaconda, because all this Terminal stuff makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: is the issue because U use the hard way, just use anaconda, the path will setup by default and create the env as in the tensorflow site, is the option after docker I think.